# Use of different formulas for capacitor impedence (phasors)

Tags: phasor

I'm confused about why I see two different formulas for calculating capacitor impedance \$Z_{cap}\$ using phasors.

For one formula in my text, I see:

$$Z_{cap} = \frac{1}{jwC}$$

And another I see:

$$Z_{cap} = \frac{-j}{wC}$$

Where \$w\$ is omega (angular frequency) and \$C\$ is the capacitor value.

Will someone enlighten me, or am I incorrect to assume these are equivalent and can be substituted for one another?

Comment: Hint: 1/j = -j.

Comment: Thank you.  So it's not treated normally,as exponential operations would normally make: 1/j = j^(-1) ??  Ex:  1/2 = 2^(-1) not -2

Comment: \$-j \cdot j = 1 \rightarrow -j = \frac{1}{j}\$ or, using exponential notation:  \$\frac{1}{j} = \frac{1}{e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}} = e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}} = \cos \frac{\pi}{2} - j \sin \frac{\pi}{2} = -j\$

Comment: j = sqrt(-1). All else comes from there. So multiply your 1st expression by j/j and you get the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both these equations are correct because \$j = \sqrt{-1} \$

We have

$$Z_{cap} = \dfrac{1}{j \ \omega \ C} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1} \ \omega \ C} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1} \ \omega \ C} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-1}} = - \dfrac{\sqrt{-1}}{\omega \ C} = - \dfrac{j}{\omega \ C}$$

Answer (score 1):

-j=1/j, so you can use any of the expressions,,

1/j = (1/j)*(1) = (1/j)*(j/j) = j/(j*j) = j/(j^2) = j/(sqrt(-1))^2 = j/-1 = -j,,

or

1/j = j^-1 = (exp(pi/2))^-1 = exp(-pi/2) = cos(-pi/2) + j*sin(-pi/2) = 0+j(-1) = -j

the reason 1/j=-j and 1/2 is not equal to -2 is the euler's identity,,[image]

Answer (score 1):

What value of \$x \text{ equals} \dfrac{1}{-x}\$ ??

Rearrange to \$x + \dfrac{1}{x}=0\$

Rearrange more to \$x^2 + 1=0\$

Solve for x like a quadratic: -

\$x = \dfrac{-b+/-\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\$

\$x = \dfrac{-0+/-\sqrt{0^2 - 4}}{2}\$

\$x = {+/-\sqrt{-1}}\$

This implies that the only value for x is +/-j because the square root of -1 is -j

Answer (score -1):

Easier way:  X = -1/X
             multiply both sides by X:  X^2 = X/-X = -1
             X = sqr (-1)